# Parse.com deserializing date type

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com.

Json response

```
{
    "AuditoriumId": "P2TTDSNTHM",
    "MovieId": "PAcklcCGGa",
    "StartDate": {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2015-12-09T01:08:00.000Z"
    },
    "createdAt": "2015-12-07T23:02:34.800Z",
    "objectId": "CSwc9M90JQ",
    "updatedAt": "2015-12-08T01:08:55.903Z"
}
```

Deserialization:

```
model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShowcaseModel>(getParseIdData(showcase + "/" + model.Order.ShowcaseId));
```

Model:

```
public class ShowcaseModel
{
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public string AuditoriumId { get; set; }
    public string MovieId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

For whatever reason parse.com sends custom user date property with __type, but doesn't do that for its own createdAt and updatedAt. It obviously throws an error regarding date format - there is __type in json string and i don't know how to fix this. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be

```
public class ShowcaseModel
{
    public string AuditoriumId { get; set; }
    public string MovieId { get; set; }
    public Startdate StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Startdate
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public DateTime iso { get; set; }
}
```

and then DeserializeObject